# How can Icontrol web page size while designing it using css ,html or YUI no matter the screen size 

Tags: html, css, yui, yui3

I`m using this one but it doesnt work in other screen sizes:-

```
body {
    background-color:#333;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-right-width: 20px;
    border-left-width: 20px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    size:100%;
    background-size:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "control the size" - you could set an explicit height and width, or use percentages to achieve a fluid layout. Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: when i display the page on different pcs i find different appearance ,i guess it is because of different screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

first of all do `margin:0;` and you can control the page size by using width and height
I do not really get why you have x-repeat when you have no image.
your border code needs

```
border-style:solid;
```

if you don not want to use solid, there are other choices

```
none
hidden
dotted
dashed
solid
double
groove
ridge
inset
outset
inherit
```

height & width.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_height.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_width.asp

(I don't really recommend using w3school for other things since it is really outdated.)